# Angular Momentum Zero Produce of Irrotational Fluid Proof

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

A cute problem that I spent a bit time on. Please help.

Consider flow domain smooth manifold in $n$ dimension $\Omega$ with boundary and some boundary data. Constant density is assumed.

Assume within the domain the position is defined as $r\in\mathcal{R}^n$ and velocity is prescribed as $u$.

Know that the angular momentum of this fluid is zero. i.e.

$\int_\Omega r\times u dx^n = 0 $

Can you prove the antisymmetric rate of strain tensor $\frac12(\nabla u-\nabla u^T$) is zero?

Thanks.

Comment: Counterexample: consider two counter-rotating vortices located symmetrically in a disk domain. The antisymmetric rate of strain tensor is not identically zero, but the total angular momentum cancels out.